# Launching a Crystal Report from a GridView row

Tags: c#, gridview, crystal-reports

I have got a `GridView` which contains a number of columns which contains details about the payment.  I want to create a report using Crystal Reports in such a way that I want to select a particular row and when I click the print button I want to get the report of that corresponding row.

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult. I often refer people to http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-string-parameter.htm

Essentially create your Crystal Report with a parameter to take the payment_id (or some form of "primary key") then set the print button to do something like:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load("PUT CRYSTAL REPORT PATH HERE\CrystalReport1.rpt");

            ParameterFieldDefinitions crParameterFieldDefinitions ;
            ParameterFieldDefinition crParameterFieldDefinition ;
            ParameterValues crParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
            ParameterDiscreteValue crParameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

            crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["payment_id"].Value.ToString();;
            crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields;
            crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions["payment_id"];
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues;

            crParameterValues.Clear();
            crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue);
            crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues);

            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh(); 

        }
    }
}
```